# How to run an Ansys workbench journal from external Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, workbench

I was looking for some information on how can I run an Ansys.wbjn file from an external python script (not Iron Python, language used to write the .wbjn file)

I've already tried 2 ways and both end up with a massive error message box:

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v162\Framework\bin\Win64\RunWB2.exe', '-R<AnsysWorkbenchScriptV2.wbjn>'])
```

and

```
ANSYSpath = r'C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v162\Framework\bin\Win64\RunWB2.exe'
filepath4 = '-R<AnsysWorkbenchScriptV2.wbjn
subprocess.Popen("%s %s" % (ANSYSpath, filepath4))
```

I know some may think that the problem is the '-Rerror message box

Comment: Lose the less-than sign; instead of "-R<Ansys..." try "-R Ansys...".

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot!